# sendmail - don't send email after update (ubuntu 16)

Tags: email, postfix

I have Sendmail on my server. This was working find until a week ago. Last week I have updated my system. After that update, Sendmail was showing error send when sending mail (in CLI). "`sendmail: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 1-8: missing '=' after ...`". I opened the config file (/etc/postfix/main.cf) and I have seen that it has been modified. Now I have commented the uncommented line (it was just string used in the config file to explain.). Now when I try to send a message, there is no error, nothing, but the message is not sent. I am new in Sendmail and I have no idea on how to trouble shooting this. Do some have any experience with Sendmail? How to start to troubleshoot in my case where. when I run command like this:

```
sendmail user@email.com < /tmp/email.txt
```

I have not error message and the email is not send.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using send mail for years.  It's soooo much easier than it was in the 90's, lemme tell ya.  Anyway, I'm not using postfix with sendmail, and I don't remember ever having to configure postfix in relation to it.  As a matter of fact, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and have no main.cf file.  Is that used for the cli?  The only time I've ever run mail from the command line, I'd used nail.

I'd copy my sendmail.conf, completely remove sendmail and reinstall it.  Then copy your old sendmail.conf back.  Of course, if you'd made any config changes to sendmail.conf, verifying they're still there after copying it back is a good idea.

If you still can't send mail, you would want to look closely at your sendmail.conf.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Finally, I restarted postfix and it worked.